# Is there a way to make my gitlab CI deploy in an environment even after my script "fails"?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a script that deploys on openstack but some times that script fails due to some selftests but my installation is still fine. I have set allow_failure: true on the job and set the flag when: always on my artifacts. But if the job fails then the environment that i deploy to points to the last successful job not the one that "failed" but still works. Is there a way make the environment always point to the latest job?

I tried setting flags like allow_failure on the job, when: always on my artifacts etc but although the artifacts are saved and the job continues afterwards the environment still only points to the latest successful job

Comment: I'd say that's something handled on the individual task. You could add something like `|| echo FAILED` to the command.

Comment: @KlausD. You mean next to the script? Like, ./run || echo FAILED?

Comment: Can you put the self-test and the deploy in separate jobs? That way, the self-test can fail even though the deploy to environment succeeds.